# Windows XP taskbar is stuck on "always on top of other windows"

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar, always-on-top

My Windows XP taskbar is stuck on "always on top of other windows".  It's always visible, even when a full-screen app is running.  I've gone into the properties of the taskbar and un-checked the box for "Keep the taskbard on top of other windows" but it makes no difference.  checked or un-checked, it's always on top of other windows.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I rebooted and things are working normally again.

Comment: the mighty powers of a fresh start :)

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when a systray Notification item is not answered?

A hidden notification item has put up a "baloon" , and  because it is a hidden systray item??
A program called "TaskbarSlapper" is being applied as a workaround.
this slapper brings up its own notification balloon, the user answers it, and the flag for telling the taskbar it can hide again is "reset" and the taskbar goes back down again.

I thought it was rather interesting, and downloaded the TaskbarSlapper, But if the real problem is addressable , I would see how that goes first.  I Unhid the hidden items and did some cleanup of the Notification Items, And it solves the problem.

Knowing that it is some item in the notifications that is trying to put up a notification, or has a message, should be enough to fix it.

Good luck, I thought it was only about W7.

Taskending explorer and re-running it via taskmanager it would also reset.